# Empty string check evaluates wrong

Tags: javascript

I have a condition checking for empty strings and it is not evaluating an empty string as expected.

I read string one char at a time:

```
isNumber(s: string) {
  console.log('char', s);
  if (s !== '' && !isNaN(Number(s))) {
    console.log('is a number');
    console.log('-------------');
    return true;
  }
  console.log('NOT a number');
  console.log('-------------');
}
```

The string is read from a csv file:

```
a,b,
c,d,e
```

The 3rd column 1st row is empty but if evaluates to true even though I have `s !== ''`, I have confirmed the char is empty with console. Why is the empty string condition not working?

**Update:**
Could this cause a non empty string? I initialise the variable with quotes then append to it.

```
cellExtraction = '';
cellExtraction += s; // <- where s should be an empty string read from file
```

Comment: What exactly does the `console.log()` show?

Comment: Are you sure it's an empty string or does it have whitespaces `"  "`?

Comment: Your expression works properly if `s` is *really* the empty string. Therefore one can only conclude that it is not. Note that `Number(s)` when `s` is a string containing zero or more space characters returns `0`, which *is* a number.

Comment: it is an empty string without any whitespaces

Comment: Try `s.charCodeAt(0)`. It should return `NaN` if it's an empty string.

Comment: @Oram it's 13, not an empty string :S

Comment: Char code 13 is "enter", which in the console looks like an empty string, but actually is a string with a line break. So somewhere you're adding a line break.

Comment: Actually, 13 is `\r` - [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).  Line break is `\n` which has a char code of 10. You can use `s.trim()` to remove it and other white space characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `Number("")` returns 0, which is a number. Since the `s !== ''` test is obviously returning `true`, it must be the case that `s` contains one or more space characters. Those also are turned into `0` by the `Number()` function; that is, `Number(" ")` is also `0`.

Comment: looking at console it appears to be an empty string, and in the file its empty, it shouldn't have any space. I'm not concerned about the Number(), can't figure out why there is space and if there isn't how its passing the condition

Comment: It's a return key, s.charCodeAt(0) = 13, it looks like an empty string in the console so I guess I could add a condition for: s.charCodeAt(0) != 13

Comment: @mattiscodings you could do that, or just do `s = s.trim();` before testing to remove leading and trailing white space.

Comment: that works even though char code 13 is a line break so I guess it removes line breaks to

Comment: @mattiscodings the "white space" category includes more than just spaces; tabs, newlines, probably some "weird" Unicode space-like things, etc